# Finding the Null space and range of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following transformation:

$$
T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3\ \ \ \ T
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x+y+z\\
y+z\\
z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I am trying to find the Null Space of $T$, $N(T)$ and the Range of $T$, $R(T)$.

I am still a little confused on the topic of transformation null space and range, but I do understand the concept of transformations and how they work.

My first guess is that the Null space would be something like:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
x\\
x
\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
x\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I'm not sure if this is correct, or if my understanding is a little flawed.

Comment: If you know $T$ then the null space (or kernel) of the transformation is simply the solution set of the homogeneous system with coefficient matrix $T$.

Comment: Oh, so it would be the solution to the Problem Ax=0, where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$
?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the matrix of transformation (in canonical basis) is $M=\left(\matrix{1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1}\right)$ and $\det M=1$ ie, T is bijective.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You have the general form of the linear mapping. The basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is rather elementary (the standard basis). What you would like to do is write the transformation in terms of some matrix that can express it and find the solution to $Ax = 0$, that is the nullity of $T$.

One of the matrices you could express this transformation as is:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$